# No logs created unless it tests

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 for logging in my app. Basically it's logging uncatched exceptions (Error.log) and logging changes of my data at service layer (journal.log; journalJSON.log).

And here's the thing, when I'm starting service layer tests every log appears in the file and console, but when I'm using application deployed in tomcat they're only in console. What's happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
<appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>


    <File name="Error" fileName="logs/error.log"
          immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern=" \n\n %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>

    <RandomAccessFile name="Journal" fileName="logs/journal.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %msg%n"/>
    </RandomAccessFile>

    <File name="JournalJSON" fileName="logs/journalJSON.log" immediateFlush="true" append="false">
        <JSONLayout complete="true" charset="UTF-8" compact="false" eventEol="false"/>
    </File>

</appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="com.user.controller" level="error" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Error" level="error"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="error"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="com.user.service" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="JournalJSON" level="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Journal" level="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Console" level="info"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="warn">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of possibilities I can think of:

1. Your configuration file isn't being found and it is using the default configuration.
2. The logger for your application isn't com.user.controller or com.user.service and the root logger is being used.